# "If you are interested in X, Y, and Z, and want to [...]" vs "If you are interested in X, Y, Z, and want to [...]"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

In the following example:

> If you are interested in computer vision, machine learning, **and** natural language processing, and want to read this book, follow this link.

Can one omit the first "and", i.e. write the sentence as follows:

> If you are interested in computer vision, machine learning, natural language processing, and want to read this book, follow this link.

?

Comment: The basic issue here is one of "parallel structure" or "parallel construction": https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/grammar/parallel-structure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, both are needed.

the first *and* is for a list, and the second *and* separates two clauses; "and want to," is not an item in the list. However, since the second clause is *dependent*, *sans* subject, the comma before it is not used.

*If you like skiing and snow-boarding and want to do so in August, go south.*